# How to use QnA maker and LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am a bit lost in terms of how to use the Microsoft QnA maker and LUIS together. If I understand correctly QnA maker only works on FAQ styled data whereas LUIS is for understanding intents and providing the answer.

So the question I have is how to get both of them to work together. First, what technologies are there and how do they determine where the calls get routed to, as in QnA maker or LUIS.

Any insights will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I used this example a few times and it seems to work.

QnAMAker is use when the user would ask a question. "How can I set an alarm on my phone"
Luis is use to execute a command/action and identify entities. "Set an alarm at three o'clock" 
Dispatch is used to route the message to the right service, either QNA or Luis (you can have more than one of each, or 5 qna and no Luis)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To expand on other answers:

QnAMaker is for direct question => answer pairs. It trains based on exact questions, such as the one exampled by Alexandre, and has exact answers.

LUIS parses the question from the user, instead of using it directly, and uses the resulting score to return an 'intent'. The bot dev then uses this score/intent to route the conversation flow to other dialogs. A good example is to think about how many ways you can say 'goodbye' (Goodbye, bye, byebye, cya, peace!, TTYL). All of these can be programmed, or trained, in LUIS to return 'Goodbye' as the main intent. Then you can code 'if Goodbye is return, go to Goodbye dialogs' into your own chatbot.

Dispatch is like an umbrella over both. At it's core, it's a LUIS model (It looks at messages and scores them). Based on that score, it returns an intent, just like LUIS. And again, like LUIS, it would be up to the bot developer to route the returned intent (if QnAIntent is returned, go to QnA dialogs). Using dispatch to route your initial intents means you don't need to hit every single one of your models (both QnA and LUIS) just to test an utterance (message from a user). Just once through dispatch.